# mongodb java groupby query conversion

Tags: java, mongodb

A mongodb newbie. I have been playing with Mongo java driver and so far it went fine.

I have been successfully using the `DBCollection.aggregate` – I was passing:

```
$match
$project
$group
$sort
```

For example, I have been setting up criteria like:

```
Map<String, Object> match_criteria;
match_criteria.put(“properties.type”, “monuments”);

DBObject match = new BasicDBObject();
match.putAll(match_criteria); //was just setting from Map
DBObject match_dbobj = new BasicDBObject("$match", match);
.
.
.
.
.in the same way was populating $project, $group and $sort
```

then was calling

```
DBCollection.aggregate(match_dbobj, project_dbobj, group_dbobj, sort_dbobj)
```

But now having problem to convert the following mongo shell query using this approach:

```
db.test.aggregate({
    $match:{             ---> still can pass with Map
        "properties.type":'monuments',
    }
},
{
    $project:{           ---> still can pass with Map
        "props.country":1,
        "attrs.time":1,
        "attrs.status":1
    }
},
{
    $group:{              ---> trying to find a way to handle $group from java code
        _id:{           
            status:'$attrs.status',
            country:'$props.country'
        },
        time:{
            $last:'$attrs.time'
        }
    }
}
)
```

How to convert the `$group` - I cannot buildup using the Map anymore. Any idea?

Comment: Use the "computed" into Aggregates.project [Look this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42793718/7691850).

Answer (score 0):

In your example `$group` is a nested DBObject so the way to create it would be:

```
// Create the group sub documents
DBObject idDocument=new BasicDBObject("status","$attrs.status").append("country","$props.country");
DBObject timeDocument=new BasicDBObject("$last","$attrs.time");

// Create the group document
DBObject groupDocument=new BasicDBObject("_id",idDocument).append("time",timeDocument);

// Create the whole group statement
DBObject group=new BasicDBObject("$group", groupDocument);
```