# MongoDB with Java - GroupBy more one column

Tags: java, mongodb

i am trying transfer the PostgreSQL for MongoDB using java.

I have the SQL

```
SELECT id_buyer, buyer, SUM(qtde)
FROM test.log
GROUP BY id_buyer, buyer
```

and my new code

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient();

        MongoDatabase db = mongoClient.getDatabase("teste");

        MongoCollection<Document> coll = db.getCollection("log");

        DBObject groupFields = new BasicDBObject();
        groupFields.put("id_buyer", "$id_buyer"); 
        groupFields.put("buyer", "$buyer");         

        AggregateIterable<Document> mongoCollectionList = coll.aggregate(
                Arrays.asList(
                        Aggregates.group(groupFields, Accumulators.sum("qtde", "$qtde")),
                        Aggregates.project(fields(include("comprador", "Quantidade")))
                ));

        MongoCursor<Document> mongoCursor = mongoCollectionList.iterator();

        while (mongoCursor.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(mongoCursor.next().toJson());

        }
```

result

```
{ "_id" : { "id_buyer" : 2, "buyer" : "COMPS" }, "qtde" : 16703 }
```

How do i remove "id_buyer" and "buyer" that is into "_id" ?

Tks

Comment: Are you asking how to remove `_id` field from the response ?  Something like `Aggregates.project(fields(excludeId(), include("comprador", "Quantidade")))`

Comment: I need remove the columns "" that are in _id column.

Today i have
{ "_id" : { "id_buyer" : 2, "buyer" : "COMPS" }, "qtde" : 16703 }

I need

{"id_buyer" : 2, "buyer" : "COMPS" , "qtde" : 16703 }

My problem is use the "groupFields" together "Aggregates.group"

Comment: You can try something like this `Aggregates.project(fields(excludeId(), computed("id_buyer", "$_id.id_buyer"),  computed("buyer", "$_id.buyer"),  include("comprador", "Quantidade")))`

Comment: It worked (Y) Thank's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42726376/mongodb-with-java-groupby-more-one-column?noredirect=1#comment72648529_42726376) posted by Veeram and it worked perfectly for me.

This was his sugestion:

```
Aggregates.project(fields(excludeId(), 
    computed("id_buyer", "$_id.id_buyer"),
    computed("buyer", "$_id.buyer"), 
    include("comprador", "Quantidade")));
```

Answer (score 0):

you try like this..

```
  AggregateIterable<Document> mongoCollectionList = collection.aggregate(
                    Arrays.asList(
                            Aggregates.group(groupFields, Accumulators.sum("qtde", "$qtde")),
                            Aggregates.project(Projections.fields(Projections.include("qtde"),Projections.excludeId()))
                    ));
```

Comment: My problem is use the "groupFields" together "Aggregates.group"

Comment: you need to import following statements,  

import com.mongodb.client.model.Aggregates;
import com.mongodb.client.model.Accumulators;
import com.mongodb.client.model.Projections;